# Twilio Notifications (API) Not Sending Notifications to Facebook Messenger

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have followed [these instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/facebook) to send a message to a user (myself) from a Facebook App (my app) using the [Twilio sample app](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/sdk-starter-node).  But no message is sent.  I understand that it should post a notification to the user from the app, i.e., from my app to my Facebook notification.  And my app is in development mode and not yet approved by FB, which is OK, per the instructions, since I am logged into FB when I run it.

[image]

The Twilio notification log says **TOTAL DELIVERIES 0**.

I used their same app and exposed it on the web using ngrok.  Then I copied the page ID that was posted to that application's log when I clicked to **Verify Web Hooks**, which appeared like this:

```
 _solution: { sid: 'default' } }
1065215577
```

I assume that is my page ID, as that is not shown on anymore by Facebook.  My FB page is https://www.facebook.com/walkerroweML

I also tried my facebook ID, not knowing whether it needs my own ID or the my page ID.

The ngrok looks show that FB is reaching out to the Twilio sample app:

```
HTTP Requests                                                                   
-------------                                                                   

POST /send-notification        200 OK                                           
GET  /notify/notify.js         200 OK                                           
GET  /notify/notify.css        200 OK                                           
GET  /notify/                  200 OK                                           
POST /send-notification        200 OK                                           
GET  /notify/notify.js         200 OK                                           
GET  /notify/notify.css        200 OK                                           
GET  /notify/                  200 O
```

In the Facebook Developer's Console the app looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The support request was updated. This issue was caused by having an incorrect page ID .

For any new reports, if you followed this section to set up the Messenger channel in Twilio (https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/facebook#create-a-facebook-messenger-configuration) you cannot change the value once it has been set.

The solution: Add a new instance of the channel and selecting a different page there and deleting the old one.  Please go to:
https://www.twilio.com/console/channels/XB93e989ba4b741738f51c3f0e12076d42 and click on **Add Another Instance** at the bottom.